# My loss is "nan" and accuracy is "0.0000e+00" in Word2Vec

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on **Word2Vec**. Here I am Classifying the texts written by 8 authors.I used Word2Vec to classify texts. When training my model, I am getting **nan as loss and 0.0000e+00 as accuracy** in every epoch.I am using 10 epochs. I am using 10 novel like books for training and 2 books for testing of each author.Since I am new to machine learning, I am not able to find out the error. The vocabulary building is the first stage and next is word2vec training. These 2 work well. But this error occur in next level, that is while using the pretrained word2Vec.

```
from string import punctuation
from os import listdir
from numpy import array
from numpy import asarray
from numpy import zeros
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D

# load doc into memory
def load_doc(filename):
    # open the file as read only
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    # read all text
    text = file.read()
    # close the file
    file.close()
    return text

# turn a doc into clean tokens
def clean_doc(doc, vocab):
    # split into tokens by white space
    tokens = doc.split()
    # remove punctuation from each token
    table = str.maketrans('', '', punctuation)
    tokens = [w.translate(table) for w in tokens]
    # filter out tokens not in vocab
    tokens = [w for w in tokens if w in vocab]
    tokens = ' '.join(tokens)
    return tokens

# load all docs in a directory
def process_docs(directory, vocab, is_trian):
    documents = list()
    # walk through all files in the folder
    for filename in listdir(directory):
        # skip any reviews in the test set
        if is_trian and filename.startswith('t'):
            continue
        if not is_trian and not filename.startswith('t'):
            continue
        # create the full path of the file to open
        path = directory + '/' + filename
        # load the doc
        doc = load_doc(path)
        # clean doc
        tokens = clean_doc(doc, vocab)
        # add to list
        documents.append(tokens)
    return documents

# load embedding as a dict
def load_embedding(filename):
    # load embedding into memory, skip first line
    file = open(filename,'r')
    lines = file.readlines()[1:]
    file.close()
    # create a map of words to vectors
    embedding = dict()
    for line in lines:
        parts = line.split()
        # key is string word, value is numpy array for vector
        embedding[parts[0]] = asarray(parts[1:], dtype='float32')
    return embedding

# create a weight matrix for the Embedding layer from a loaded embedding
def get_weight_matrix(embedding, vocab):
    # total vocabulary size plus 0 for unknown words
    vocab_size = len(vocab) + 1
    # define weight matrix dimensions with all 0
    weight_matrix = zeros((vocab_size, 100))
    # step vocab, store vectors using the Tokenizer's integer mapping
    for word, i in vocab.items():
        weight_matrix[i] = embedding.get(word)
    return weight_matrix

# load the vocabulary
vocab_filename = 'vocab.txt'
vocab = load_doc(vocab_filename)
vocab = vocab.split()
vocab = set(vocab)

# load all training reviews
a1 = process_docs('txt/author1', vocab, True)
a2 = process_docs('txt/author2', vocab, True)
a3 = process_docs('txt/author3', vocab, True)
a4 = process_docs('txt/author4', vocab, True)
a5 = process_docs('txt/author5', vocab, True)
a6 = process_docs('txt/author6', vocab, True)
a7 = process_docs('txt/author7', vocab, True)
a8 = process_docs('txt/author8', vocab, True)
a9 = process_docs('txt/author9', vocab, True)
train_docs = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 +a9


# create the tokenizer
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
# fit the tokenizer on the documents
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(train_docs)

# sequence encode
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_docs)
# pad sequences
max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in train_docs])
Xtrain = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
# define training labels
ytrain = array([0 for _ in range(10)] + [1 for _ in range(10)] + [2 for _ in range(10)] + [3 for _ in 
range(10)] + [4 for _ in range(10)] + [5 for _ in range(10)] + [6 for _ in range(10)] + [7 for _ in 
range(10)] + [8 for _ in range(10)])

# load all test reviews
a1 = process_docs('txt/author1', vocab, False)
a2 = process_docs('txt/author2', vocab, False)
a3 = process_docs('txt/author3', vocab, False)
a4 = process_docs('txt/author4', vocab, False)
a5 = process_docs('txt/author5', vocab, False)
a6 = process_docs('txt/author6', vocab, False)
a7 = process_docs('txt/author7', vocab, False)
a8 = process_docs('txt/author8', vocab, False)
a9 = process_docs('txt/author9', vocab, False)
test_docs = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8 +a9

# sequence encode
encoded_docs = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_docs)
# pad sequences
Xtest = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
# define test labels
ytest = array([0 for _ in range(2)] + [1 for _ in range(2)] + [2 for _ in range(2)] + [3 for _ in 
range(2)] + [4 for _ in range(2)] + [5 for _ in range(2)] + [6 for _ in range(2)] + [7 for _ in 
range(2)] +[8 for _ in range(2)])

# define vocabulary size (largest integer value)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

# load embedding from file
raw_embedding = load_embedding('embedding_word2vec.txt')
# get vectors in the right order
embedding_vectors = get_weight_matrix(raw_embedding, tokenizer.word_index)
# create the embedding layer
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_vectors], input_length=max_length, 
trainable=False)

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=5, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
print(model.summary())
# compile network
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit network
model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain, epochs=10, verbose=2)
# evaluate
loss, acc = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, verbose=0)
print('Test Accuracy: %f' % (acc*100))
```

Comment: Can you share  txt files and all other support files to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using custom built word embeddings? Could it be possible that input words are not present in your vocabulary used for embedding?